# Implementing redis in go

Tags: go, redis

I am trying implement redis basic functionality like below in Go.

1. GET
2. SET
3. ZADD
4. ZCARD
5. ZCOUNT
6. ZRANGE
7. SAVE

Comment: Are you trying to use redis from the go language, or do you actually mean you want to implement a system with the same functionality as redis?

Comment: I want to implement redis like system with above functionality

Comment: If you're after creating a Redis client in Go, there are already [lots of implementations](https://godoc.org/?q=redis) with some of them being quite mature.

Comment: As i said I want to implement whole redis(with basic functionality) in Go not the go client for Redis. I am learning Go and planning to do some small project. I thought this could be a good start.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to implement a Go server offering some Redis features, it is quite easy. You need to decide about the goroutine model, then implement/reuse some data structures (map and skiplist), then implement the Redis protocol (which is simple enough).

I would suggest a goroutine model with 2 goroutines per client connection, plus one goroutine to implement the Redis engine and manage the data structures. The benefit of this model is you can easily support pipelining and the atomicity property of Redis commands without any explicit locking. This model is well adapted if you want to later extend the scope by supporting blocking commands (such as the ones useful for queues).

Now, if you also want to mimic the same exact Redis behavior, this is more complex. Especially, saving the data in background leveraging the OS copy-on-write mechanism will be difficult with Go (since forking does not work). For a memory database, foreground saving is always easy. Background saving is extremely difficult.

You may also want to have a look at the following attempts, and simplify/enrich them to match your goals:

- https://github.com/siddontang/ledisdb
- https://github.com/felixge/go-redis
- https://github.com/docker/go-redis-server